# Using react-css-modules with an iframe component

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

When defining a component using iframes (eg, via https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component) - how would you integrate the global styles into the iframe itself when using react-css-modules?

Comment: I guess :global doesn't work with iframe?

Comment: I don't actually use :global et al - for now, I simply have a bootstrap.css and a custom.css which I dump into a single CSS file. My guess is it won't work for an iframe anyway since the document root is completely different. I can inject the styles into this frame though, but then react-css-modules don't pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a non-global wrapper class and place all global styles inside. Then it works in iframe for me. Example:

JSX:

```
<div className={styles.globalStylesWrapper}>
     <!-- elements with global styles -->
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.globalStylesWrapper {
  :global {
    // Copy global styles here
  }
}
```